# Rust - Get component in Vec<Box dyn ComponentTrait>> (ECS)

Tags: rust, entity-component-system

I'am a junior developer with Rust language.
I come from JavaScript and a lot of features and specificities are still unclear to me.

Currently, I'm looking to build my own ECS (entity component system) system in Rust.
I'am stay stuck when i want to get an component from an entity.

Actualy i store component in entity with an dyn boxed vector, it's that a good way?

My code:

```rust
enum ComponentEnum {
    Position,
    Size
}

trait Component {}

// Position Component
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd, Debug)]
struct Position {
    x: i32,
    y: i32
}

// Size Component
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd, Debug)]
struct Size {
    height: i32,
    width: i32
}

impl Component for Position {}
impl Component for Size {}

struct Entity {
    id: usize,
    components: Vec<Box<dyn Component>>
}

impl Entity {
    fn new(index: usize) -> Self {
        Entity { id: index, components: vec![] }
    }

    // Add a component in Entity
    fn add_component<T: 'static + Component>(&mut self, component: T) {
        self.components.push(Box::new(component));
    }
}

struct EntityStore {
    entities: Vec<Entity>,
    current_index: usize,
}
impl EntityStore {
    fn new() -> EntityStore {
        EntityStore { entities: vec![], current_index: 0 }
    }

    fn generate_index(&self) -> usize {
        unimplemented!();
    }

    // Stop creation system and update EntityStore current_index
    fn end(&mut self) -> &mut Entity {
        let entity = self.entities.get_mut(self.current_index).unwrap();
        self.current_index = self.current_index + 1;
        entity
    }

    fn create_entity(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        let mut entity = Entity::new(self.current_index);
        self.entities.push(entity);

        self
    }

    // Add component to entity
    fn with_component<T: 'static + Component>(&mut self, component: T) ->  &mut Self {
        let mut entity = self.entities.get_mut(self.current_index).unwrap();
        entity.add_component(component);

        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut es = EntityStore::new();

    // Make entity
    let mut entity1 = es
        .create_entity()
        .with_component(Position { x: 0, y: 0 })
        .with_component(Size { height: 10, width: 10 })
        .end();

    // Get entity position component
    // let component_position_entity1 = entity1.get_component(ComponentEnum::Position);
}
```

How can I get my Position component back from my entity?

EDIT:

Here, a test function to get a component (in Entity implementation) :

```rust
fn get_component(&mut self, component_enum: ComponentEnum) { //want return Position or Size component
        let mut entity_components = &self.components;

        // Search component by Name ?
        // Currently, i try to compare Component trait with Component Enum element...
        let component = entity_components
            .iter_mut()
            .find(|component| component == component_enum)
            .unwrap();

        // Here, the component type is "&mut Box<dyn Component>" but i want type like "&mut Position" or "&mut Size"

        component // Here i need to return a Position or Size struct component, but i have Component Trait so i can't use Position/Size functions
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual question here? Does the code not compile, or does it not work as expected - or are you just looking for code review? It would help if you described the actual problem you want solved rather than a completely abstract pattern like "entity component system", which might not map well to Rust, and might not even be needed for what you're working on.

Comment: Hi! 
Sorry about that, my question is : With my current code, how can I get a component from an entity ?

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks like `&entity[index]` should work. Please show us what you tried and _where_ you are stuck - for example, did you write a `get_component()` function, but it failed to compile? Also, please keep in mind that not everyone is acquainted with the particular pattern you are trying to implement.

Comment: I have updated my post with test function to get a component ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use enums to differentiate between components types (bear in mind I have very little experience with ECS systems in general). Then you have various ways of getting one type, but I have made a method `get_component`, that takes a closure to use when finding the right components. You can then pass it a closure that checks for a position component specifically.

This is my implementation, based on your example:

```rust
// Position Component
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd, Debug)]
struct Position {
    x: i32,
    y: i32
}

// Size Component
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd, Debug)]
struct Size {
    height: i32,
    width: i32
}

#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd, Debug)]
enum Component {
    Position(Position),
    Size(Size)
}

struct Entity {
    id: usize,
    components: Vec<Component>
}

impl Entity {
    fn new(index: usize) -> Self {
        Entity { id: index, components: vec![] }
    }

    // Add a component in Entity
    fn add_component(&mut self, component: Component) {
        self.components.push(component);
    }
    
    fn get_component(&self, pred: impl Fn(&&Component) -> bool) -> Option<&Component>{
        self.components.iter().find(pred)
    }
    
}

struct EntityStore {
    entities: Vec<Entity>,
    current_index: usize,
}
impl EntityStore {
    fn new() -> EntityStore {
        EntityStore { entities: vec![], current_index: 0 }
    }

    fn generate_index(&self) -> usize {
        unimplemented!();
    }

    // Stop creation system and update EntityStore current_index
    fn end(&mut self) -> &mut Entity {
        let entity = self.entities.get_mut(self.current_index).unwrap();
        self.current_index = self.current_index + 1;
        entity
    }

    fn create_entity(&mut self) -> &mut Self {
        let mut entity = Entity::new(self.current_index);
        self.entities.push(entity);

        self
    }

    // Add component to entity
    fn with_component(&mut self, component: Component) ->  &mut Self {
        let mut entity = self.entities.get_mut(self.current_index).unwrap();
        entity.add_component(component);

        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut es = EntityStore::new();

    // Make entity
    let mut entity1 = es
        .create_entity()
        .with_component(Component::Position(Position { x: 0, y: 0 }))
        .with_component(Component::Size(Size { height: 10, width: 10 }))
        .end();

    // Get entity position component
    let component_position_entity1 = entity1.get_component(|c| if let Component::Position(_) = c { true} else {false});
    println!("{:?}", component_position_entity1);
}
```

Note that there many alternatives to my `get_component`, but my main point is to use enums to differentiate component types and to not use `Box<dyn Component>`.

Answer (score 0):

@user4815162342 posted this in the comments to index into `entity.components` directly:

like this:

```
    fn main() {
        let mut es = EntityStore::new();
    
        // Make entity
        let mut entity1 = es
            .create_entity()
            .with_component(Position { x: 0, y: 0 })
            .with_component(Size { height: 10, width: 10 })
            .end();
    
        // Get entity position component
        let v0 = &entity1.components[0];
        let v1 = &entity1.components[1];
        v0.display();
        v1.display();
    }
```

But since the index depends on the order that the entities were added, then you'd be much better off storing the entities components in a hash map, or with an `enum` tag to make it clearer what each component is.